# How to properly render an embedded Font?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, fonts, render, embedded-resource

I download a True Type Font and I embedded it just as [this page](https://www.codeguru.com/columns/vb/embedding-fonts-in-visual-basic-apps.html) explains.
I had to set the `UseCompatibleTextRendering` property to be able to load it but it looks very weird, I don't know why it looks good in the browser but not in the application.

Just to be clear I added the font to my resources, set it as embedded resource, I used this module:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Drawing.Text
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module ExternalFontType
    Public Function GetFont(aAssembly As Assembly,
      strFontName As String, intFontSize As Integer,
      fsFontStyle As FontStyle) As Font

        Using pcolFonts As New PrivateFontCollection

            Dim bFont() As Byte = ExternalFontType.bRawFontData(aAssembly, strFontName)
            Dim ptrMemFont As IntPtr =
               Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(bFont.Length)

            Marshal.Copy(bFont, 0, ptrMemFont, bFont.Length)
            pcolFonts.AddMemoryFont(ptrMemFont, bFont.Length)

            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptrMemFont)

            Return New Font(pcolFonts.Families(0),
               intFontSize, fsFontStyle)
        End Using
    End Function

    Private Function bRawFontData(aAssembly As Assembly, strFontName As String) As Byte()
        Using stFont As Stream =
            aAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(strFontName)

            If (stFont Is Nothing) Then Throw _
               New Exception(String.Format("Cannot load _
            font '{0}'", strFontName))

            Dim bFontBuffer() As Byte = New _
               Byte(CInt(stFont.Length - 1)) {}

            stFont.Read(bFontBuffer, 0, CInt(stFont.Length))
            Return bFontBuffer
        End Using
    End Function
End Module
```

and included it in this code

```
lbl.UseCompatibleTextRendering = True
lbl.Font = ExternalFontType.GetFont(Me.GetType.Assembly, "ProyectName.FontName.ttf", 15, FontStyle.Bold)
```

Answer (score 2):

More than one problem with that code:

1. The [PrivateFontCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection) cannot be declared with a `Using` statement: this collection must be preserved as long as the Fonts it points to are needed. It's usually declared as a Field in the class (Form) that uses it or in a shared class (or Module, here), then disposed of when not needed anymore.
2. `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem()` cannot be used here; it's a *temptation* to call it after  `Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem()`, but not in this occasion. This can (will) compromise the Font data allocation. What you need to do is dispose of the `PrivateFontcollection` object. The Framework will take care of the COM *affair* (it will do it for you even if you *forget* to dispose of the `PrivateFontcollection` object. You should try not to forget, though).
3. The assembly reference is not required: the Font is added to the Project's Resources as a byte array, which is all that's needed. It can then be retrieved either by name, e.g., `My.Resources.SomeFontName`, or using the [ResourceManager.GetObject()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager.getobject) method, casting the returned object to `Byte()`:

   ```
   Dim fontData As Byte() = My.Resources.SomeFontName
   Dim fontData As Byte() = DirectCast(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("SomeFontName"), Byte())
   ```

▶ You have already mentioned this but let's say it again: not all controls can use these Fonts. Only controls that can use Fonts drawn by GDI+ can actually use Fonts from the `PrivateFontCollection`, the Label and Button controls are among of these, in fact both expose a [UseCompatibleTextRendering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label.usecompatibletextrendering) property. A RichTextBox, for example, cannot.

- If the Font is created correctly, you can use **`Graphics.DrawString()`** to draw strings content using that Font, even when you cannot set it as the Font of a Control.

```
Private myFontCollection As PrivateFontCollection = New PrivateFontCollection()
```

In the Form's Constructor, add Font from the Project's Resources.

- Here I'm using a helper class, **`FontManager`**, which exposes a `public shared` method `AddFontsFromResource()`: pass to this method the `PrivateFontCollection` and a list of resources names corresponding to the Font names.
  This method fills the collection with Fonts that can be installed successfully and returns the number of Fonts installed.
  Of course you use whatever other method you prefer to reference your Fonts.
- **Note**. In the example, three Font resources are added to the collection:
  `{"FontFamily1Regular", "FontFamily1Italics", "OtherFontFamily"}`
  but two belong to the same `FontFamily`, so the `PrivateFontCollection` will contain just two elements, not three.

```
Public Sub New()
    Dim installedFontsCount = FontManager.AddFontsFromResources(myFontCollection, 
        {"FontFamily1Regular", "FontFamily1Italics", "OtherFontFamily"})
    ' The Font can set here or anywhere else
    someLabel.UseCompatibleTextRendering = True
    someLabel.Font = New Font(myFontCollection.Families(0), 10.5F, FontStyle.Regular)
    someButton.UseCompatibleTextRendering = True
    someButton.Font = New Font(myFontCollection.Families(0), 10.5F, FontStyle.Italic)
End Sub
```

It's important to dispose of the `PrivateFontCollection` when it's not needed anymore: when the Form that initialized it closes or before the Application closes:
You could also use a shared object to reference a `PrivateFontCollection` that can be used anywhere in the Project. In this case the collection needs to be disposed of when the Application closes.

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed
    myFontCollection.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Helper class:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Text
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class FontManager
    Public Shared Function AddFontsFromResources(fontCollection As PrivateFontCollection, fontNames As String()) As Integer
    If fontNames.Length = 0 Then Return Nothing
    Dim installedFontsCount = 0

    For Each fontName As String In fontNames
        Try
            Dim fontData As Byte() = CType(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(fontName), Byte())
            If fontData Is Nothing Then Throw New InvalidOperationException()

            Dim data As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(fontData.Length)
            Marshal.Copy(fontData, 0, data, fontData.Length)
            fontCollection.AddMemoryFont(data, fontData.Length)
            installedFontsCount += 1
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Placeholder: Notify User/Log/Whatever
            Debug.Print($"Font installation failed for {fontName}")
        End Try
    Next
    Return installedFontsCount
    End Function
End Class
```

---

C# version:

```csharp
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static int AddFontsFromResources(PrivateFontCollection fontCollection, string[] fontNames)
{
    int installedFontsCount = 0;
    if (fontNames.Length == 0) return 0;

    foreach (string fontName in fontNames) {
        try {
            byte[] fontData = (byte[])Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(fontName);
            var data = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(fontData.Length);
            Marshal.Copy(fontData, 0, data, fontData.Length);
            fontCollection.AddMemoryFont(data, fontData.Length);
            installedFontsCount += 1;
        }
        catch (Exception) {
            // Placeholder: Notify User/Log/Whatever
            Console.WriteLine($"Font installation failed for {fontName}");
        }
    }
    return installedFontsCount;
}
```

Comment: :o Thank you very much for taking the time to explain me this @jimi sempai, but I have 2 questions, 1st one, why you use an "F" in the font size?, 2nd one, why you use `String.Empty`?, I allways use "" to declare my string variables.

Comment: `F` means `float` (`Single` in VB.Net). This is the type that the Font constructor expects, I'm just declaring it explicitly. You can also write, e.g., `10.5`, it's also accepted. In C#, you have to write `10.5F` instead. `String.Empty` is simply the standard form to declare a string that doesn't contain any chars. You can also use `= ""`, it doesn't change the result.

Comment: Hi again @jimi, I had a new question, If I were making a custom text box, where would it be appropriate to call the `myfontcollection.dispose()`? (this is the code that im using [link](https://pastebin.com/AzJK4tAa))

Comment: As always, in the `Dispose()` method override. You'll have `protected overrides sub Dispose(disposing as Boolean) if disposing then myFontCollection?.Dispose() end if MyBase.Dispose(disposing) end sub`. Btw, change `OnCreateControl()` to `OnHandleCreated()`, move `installedFontsCount = FontManager.AddFontsFromResource(...)` to the constructor ( `public sub new() `). Also, when you create a Custom Control, don't subscribe to events, override the methods that raise the events. So, remove all `AddHandler` parts and use instead, e.g. `Protected overrides OnEnter()`. Remove `JoinEvents(True)`

Comment: [...] And make sure `installedFontsCount > 0` before you set the Font. -- Does the code posted here answer your question? If so, you should accept it. If you have other questions, please post a new actual question: it's not really useful for anyone else answering unrelated questions in the comments section.

Comment: not really, the question was, how to properly render a  external font?, because it looks different from the webbrowser [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/1622952) but only in a specific size, in the end I thought it was a minor problem and decided to leave it like that, but your explanation was really useful to improve my code.