# VB.net - using a string as resource name to make code more customizable

Tags: vb.net, my.resources

I would like to put the name of a resource into a string, because this resource name appears everywhere in the code and this prevents quick changes.

```
Dim fontMemPointer As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(My.Resources.DIGITALDREAMNARROW.Length)
```

You see a font name in this case called "DIGITALDREAMNARROW".
I tried declare a string in which I put the font name so I can quickly use other fonts.

```
Dim MyFont As String = "DIGITALDREAMNARROW"
Dim fontMemPointer As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(My.Resources.MyFont.Length)
```

But obviously, the part after My.Resources. is an exact literal name which is not interpreted as a string. Is there a technique to solve this?

Comment: See the `AddFontsFromResources()` method shown here: [How to properly render an embedded Font?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64512339/7444103)

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. Alas I need concrete simple examples: I am not capable to understand abstract professional descriptions of code.

Comment: There's no very much to understand. Get the `AddFontsFromResources()` method: as you can see, it uses Resources by name to install embedded Fonts. The `My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(fontName)` method call creates an Object from a string, the name of a Resource. You then need to cast the object to the actual Type, which is `Byte()`, in that case. Or `Image` if you embedded an Bitmap of some kind, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and your efforts but after reading this several times I have no clue as to what you could possibly mean. I can only create apps by examining existing code and guessing what it does. The descriptions of methods and objects are beyond me. I will just use find and replace to change the font name everywhere. Sorry.