# VB.NET - Adding a custom font and selecting from properties

Tags: vb.net, fonts

Does anyone know how I can add a new custom font into visual studio and then be able to select it from the properties menu?

Example I add Poppins font, install into OS. I want to be able to edit a labels font to that new font in the properties screen. I do not want to do it programmably.

Thanks

Comment: If the Font is a *true* TTF font, after you have installed it, it will be available in the Font dialog. If it's not, you have to add it to a PrivateFontCollection at run-time. Note that the  Font won't be available in the machines where you install your app if you don't *bring it with you* in a way or another. Adding it to the Project resource is one way. At that point...

Comment: In that case , see the notes here: [How to properly render an embedded Font?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64512339/7444103) -- Note that, even if you cannot set the Font property of all Controls, you can draw it anywhere.