# Why is my font not being used in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, memory, fonts

I've been trying to develop a small app as a learning experience, but I have been unable to find the issue to this problem. I have been trying to load a font (Roboto Medium) into memory, in order for the computer to properly display the text. But for some reason, this code doesn't seem to do this. All of my text in the explorer have the `roboto-medium` TrueType font chosen, I have made sure that the font is embedded, and I call the `LoadFont()` method before the `InitializeComponent()` method is performed. Why is this happening?

```
namespace exampleNamespace
{
    // Class used for main design system
    public partial class Design
    {

        // Private font collection variable for roboto medium font
        public PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();

        // Loads font into memory from Form.cs
        public void LoadFont()
        {
            int fontLength = Properties.Resources.roboto_medium.Length;
            byte[] fontdata = Properties.Resources.roboto_medium;
            IntPtr data = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(fontLength);
            Marshal.Copy(fontdata, 0, data, fontLength);
            pfc.AddMemoryFont(data, fontLength);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Read the notes here: [How to properly render an embedded Font?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64512339/7444103)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set `true` using `Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault`.

The documentation says for memory fonts,

> To use the memory font, text on a control must be rendered with GDI+.
> Use the SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault method, passing true, to set
> GDI+ rendering on the application

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.addmemoryfont?view=windowsdesktop-5.0#System_Drawing_Text_PrivateFontCollection_AddMemoryFont_System_IntPtr_System_Int32_

Below link explains, how to set in the main function. The default is `false`, change it to `true`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.setcompatibletextrenderingdefault?view=windowsdesktop-5.0

Comment: I just changed this setting in `Program.cs` and it still isn't fixed. Do you have any idea as to what the issue might be?

Comment: Ok. Can you also try calling AddFontMemResourceEx  before AddMemoryFont. The AddFontMemResourceEx function adds the font resource from a memory image to the system. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-addfontmemresourceex

Comment: something like this.

Comment: uint cFonts = 0;
 AddFontMemResourceEx(data, (uint)fontdata .Length, IntPtr.Zero, ref cFonts);

Answer (score 0):

In Visual C# 2005 or later, a call to `SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault` is automatically generated in the Program.cs file. To change the text rendering default, modify the generated code to `true`.

```
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(true);
```

The UseCompatibleTextRendering property is intended to provide visual compatibility between Windows Forms controls that render text using the TextRenderer class and .NET Framework 1.0 and .NET Framework 1.1 applications that perform custom text rendering using the Graphics class. In most cases, if your application is not being upgraded from .NET Framework 1.0 or .NET Framework 1.1, it is recommended that you leave UseCompatibleTextRendering set to the default value of false.